# Getting option values and using them in button to load specific urls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having three different option fields and a button to submit the form and I want to load a specific URL for each combination of values from the option fields. I am new in JavaScript hence I will be very thankful for any kind of solution either in JS or jQuery.

**Here are the code:**

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return valiadte()">
  <label for="drp1" style="font-weight: bold;">Pakket</label><br />
  <select name="drp1" id="drp1">
    <optgroup label="&#10003; Een optie kiezen">
      <option value="Een optie kiezen">Een optie kiezen</option>
      <option value="Lite">Lite</option>
      <option value="Plus">Plus</option>
      <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br /><br />

  <label for="drp2" style="font-weight: bold;">Aantal Contacten</label
        ><br />
        <select name="drp2" id="drp2">
          <optgroup label="&#10003; Een optie kiezen">
            <option value="v1">Een optie kiezen</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="2500">2500</option>
            <option value="50000">50000</option>
            <option value="75000">75000</option>
            <option value="100000">100000</option>
            <option value="150000">150000</option>
            <option value="200000">200000</option>
            <option value="250000">250000</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <label for="drp3" style="font-weight: bold;">Betaaltermijn</label><br />
  <select name="drp3" id="drp3">
    <optgroup label="&#10003; Een optie kiezen">
      <option value="o1">Een optie kiezen</option>
      <option value="Maandelijks">Maandelijks</option>
      <option value="Jaarlijks">Jaarlijks</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <hr />
  <br />

  <button type="submit" id="button">In winkelmand</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I just want to create a **handler** function which will work on **onclick** event. In the handler, I want to execute conditional statements which eventually loads a single URL for a single combination of option values. Please I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `click` on the `select`?

Comment: `$(function(){
  $('#drp1').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});`

Comment: But how to combine values from all three fields.

Comment: Same process, different Elements.

Comment: You have a typo in your `onsubmit` method, it should most likely be `validate()`. Inside this routine you can either use `if (document.getElementById("drp1").value === 'condition' && document.getElementById("drp2").value === 'other_condition') { location.href = "mytarget.html"; }` (Vanilla JS) or `if ($('#drp1').val() === 'condition' && ... ` (JQuery) to redirect the user.